# Добрый день. Кнопки нужно расположить в верхней правой части,а не в правой нижней. К сожалению, не получается исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt5

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        bt_1 = QPushButton("btn1")
        bt_2 = QPushButton("btn2")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn_1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn_2)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: И кто вас, новичков, учит вызывать `show` внутри конструктора... \*ворчит старый дед* :) Еще у вас в коде ошибка, в `hbox.addWidget(btn_1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет метод `addStretch`. Он прижимает виджеты к указанной стороне:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')

        bt_1 = QPushButton("btn1")
        bt_2 = QPushButton("btn2")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(bt_1)
        hbox.addWidget(bt_2)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для `QHBoxLayout`: если сначала вызывается `addStretch`, а после добавляются виджеты, то они будут прижаты к правой стороне, если после виджетов -- к левой.

Для `QVBoxLayout`: если сначала вызывается `addStretch`, а после добавляются виджеты, то они будут прижаты к низу, иначе к верху.

Схематично то, что в коде выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если мне надо прижать сильнее к краю или же отдалить, что использовать для этого?

Comment: А что значит сильнее? И что значит отдалить? Это какой-то отступ задать? Если нужен отступ, то используйте addSpacing и в нем указывайте количество, например `hbox.addSpacing(20)`

Comment: сократить расстояние между кнопками и расположить их в самом углу окна(прям под "Закрыть", "Восстановить", "Свернуть").

Comment: За расстояние между виджетами в layout'ах отвечает свойство setSpacing. Например, `hbox.setSpacing(0)`

Comment: Добавлю, а за расстояние слева, справа, сверху и снизу в layout отвечает метод setContentsMargins -- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins